# Update servers, build first ap, then migrate or build first web app, update servers, then migrate

Tags: 2013, content-migration

I'm building a new SharePoint farm to test migration of old, old, old MOSS content to SP13. Using a migration tool to migrate content, but need recommendation for build sequence:

**Option 1:** build farm, build web app, apply all service packs, etc to get to current release, use migration tool to migrate old content to web app.

**Option 2:** build farm, apply all updates, SPack, etc, build web app, migrate old content to web app
or does it really matter?

Answer (score 0):

Your basically stating the same thing.  Build and configure your target farm to production standards.  This should include any security items that must be completed to secure the server.  Make sure everything is working, including all services you require. Once you know you have a farm in good working state, back that thing up!

Now you can deploy your tool and start testing the migration of your content.  You know you are working from a known "good state" - so once you brings things over and they start to break - you know its the content or some missing dependency you have to resolve (i.e. your not chasing ghosts from a bad server deployment).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Option 2, in which i would install the SharePoint bits, then apply all the CU / Service packs, then run the config wizard and configure it.

Now i will create web apps and services apps as per requirement. Test it, Now i will install the migration tool and start migration.

Note: it really does not matter but the option 2 will give you less trouble and less work, you will run config wizard only once( after installing all updates).